# how to make images show in two lines when use float:left

Tags: css

```
<style>
.thumbnail
{
float: left;
width: 60px;
border: 1px solid #999;
margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
}
</style>
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src="images/image.gif" alt="" width="60" height="60"><br>
Caption
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src="images/image.gif" alt="" width="60" height="60"><br>
Caption
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src="images/image.gif" alt="" width="60" height="60"><br>
Caption
</div>

<br />
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src="images/image.gif" alt="" width="60" height="60"><br>
Caption
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src="images/image.gif" alt="" width="60" height="60"><br>
Caption
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src="images/image.gif" alt="" width="60" height="60"><br>
Caption
</div>
```

Question:

I want to show 6 imgs in two lines, so I use `<br />` after the first 3 images, but it does not work, the last 3 imgs still show at the right side of the first 3 imgs, they just start from a new line, can anyone explain why this happen? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/4KMhC/

`<br />` is for line break - It's for inline elements. It doesn't play with floats.

Floats are like gravity turned sideways... sort of...

You want to float the .thumbnails left --- then, based on their outer container, in this case, the body ... they will have a left directional gravity and naturally break when they run out of room (to the next "line") or  however you choose to think about it. If you ask a more detailed question - I might give you a more detailed answer. Let me know when you are ready. I hope this is helpfull / and not so responsive that it is scary.

CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* use box-sizing --- it moves the padding inside the box instead of outside ... win! */

html, body { /* basic reset */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.thumbnail {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333%;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

.thumbnail img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="thumbnail" />
    <h3>Caption</h3> <!-- arbitrary img size -->
</div>
```

Comment: A little snappy there sheriff!

Comment: ;-( oops! Totally unintended. I always come off weird. ! but I answer the question, so I hope that shows how much I care.

Comment: It's the box-shadows on inner elements that I was pointing out as an example problem. There are plenty of reasons to go with the clear fix besides that. especially when you are reusing styles, it ends up being a set it and forget it sort of thing. See this: http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/JwxAs  --- I have a clear-fix on the 3 reused structural classes... then I'm set.

Comment: @sheriffderek aaa I see, I personally use `.clear:after {clear: both; content: ' '; display: table;}` but it is not supported in ie8, anyways thanks for the info, time to delete my answer and award you +1

Comment: I thought of another good reason! http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/VsbcB/   -- don't delete your answer!!! That's how we learn this stuff!!!

Comment: There are great reasons for each.

Comment: It's a 2 part question. That is a unique answer to the second question. Why do you think the user is employing line breaks? I think it's because they are learning - and I wouldn't want to encourage the use of line breaks without good reason. I only find them useful to break lines of text, such as an h1 that I want to span three lines and align left.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this** and **Remove Br** `Tag`

```
.clr{clear:both;}
```

**Replace** `br` into this  `<div class="clr"></div>`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NhpDJ/)**

Comment: Don't need to clear both... this works - but to be clear, when you say you are clearing: left; you are sending each float: left down to the next space available after the previous block. This isn't so much as "can anyone explain why this happen?" as much as it is just a quick fix with no learning. + it doesn't really show where to use the .clr div ...

Answer (score 1):

without touching up markup you can set br to `clear: both;` [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MW2D7/)

But best practice is to wrap your div like this

```
<div>
<!---your floating div-->
<!---your floating div-->
<!---your floating div-->
</div>
<div>
<!---your floating div-->
<!---your floating div-->
<!---your floating div-->
</div>
```

Then you can apply `display: table-row;`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MW2D7/1/)

Comment: If your loop, assuming that you might populate this list (this should be a list) with php or something ---- is going to be more than 3 items at a time, this isn't going to do the trick as far as reusable code. But definitely not an approach I thought of. So, cool!

Answer (score 0):

In your css add a class that has `clear:right;` like so:

```
.clearfix {
  clear:right;
}
```

Now add that class to your 3rd element and the images after it should go to the other line.

[CSS: clear documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/HPyXZ/2/

```
   .thumbnail
{
float: left;
width: 60px;
border: 1px solid #999;
margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
}

.clearboth{
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Why "both" instead of left? I don't see any right's to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

unless you really need to use float attribute, you could use the `display` attribute to change how `divs` are positioned in the page flaw like this :

```
.thumbnail{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
}
```

Personally I prefer this approach to the `float` one because is more clean (never really liked all those `clear` and `overflow` attributes out of nowhere), actually explains what you're doing (i.e. you want them divs to be displayed as same line blocks), doesn't involve `float` attribute which may be troublesome when positioning other elements.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MBQtF/)

Comment: This is nice, however, there will be uncontrollable space on the right - as far as I remember. I don't feel like a jerk when I say that everyone should be using box-sizing and ems instead of pixels now - as I might have a year ago. I've been doing a lot of stuff with inline-block and vertical align middle lately and it has tons of useful scenarios, that's for sure.

Comment: thanks I never thought 'bout that space on the right... it seems thought you can still use display:inline-block on a wrapper div and continue positioning on its right as in this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/MBQtF/4/

Comment: Make your browser larger and smaller... The little viewport in the fiddle -- whacky stuff happens. It's not that it doesn't work, but there are uncontrollable things happening - and I just don't think it's really the best way to target things. Leaving the br in there isn't keeping the markup and the style separate. For clean reusable / easily maintainable code - we should look for the most 007 smooth option.

Comment: Now, if we needed all of these things to be in a line - and the things were different sizes - so they needed to be vertical-align: middle; - well then we would do that - (but then the space)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your problem there are many ways:

1) Add a class that encloses all thumbanil

```
<style>
...
.box{ width:300px;}

</style>

<div class="box">
...
</div>
```

2) Use CSS3 "column-count" but does not work in IE9

```
<style>
.thumbnail
{
width: 60px;
border: 1px solid #999;
margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
}
.box{column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-count:3;
width: 300px;
}

</style>
```

Remove the float from thumbnail, and you can chose the number of columns if you have more thumbnail.

3)Use "clear:both"

```
<style>
.clear{clear:both;}
</style>

<div class="box">
...

<div class="clear"></div>

...
</div>
```

I hope I was helpful. Bye.

Comment: Instead of down voting you, I'll just say that I feel that this is an overcomplicated answer to a very un-described problem. If this was responsive, (which it should be) - this would bring in a whole different style of thinking. + the User is employing px, so we should assume that internet explorer 6+ are important to them. Columns really aren't solving anything that floats cant, unlike long columns of text, where they really start making a ton of sense. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the first 3 images in a div , then put the second 3 images in another div , css styling for each div with "clear:both",like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .img_wrap{clear:both;}
</style>
<div class="img_wrap">
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
</div>
<div class="img_wrap">
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  <div class="thumbnail"></div>
</div>
```

I'm green ,hope that can help you !